# JSSOR drag does not work in responsive mode

Tags: slider, jssor

MOBILE ISSUE ONLY. VIEW ON YOUR PHONE.
I have complete working jssor implementation. 
See here : http://www.followupapp.co/learn/learnkonvav2.html

However I took a responsive template and added above code to it. The dragging does not let me scroll past all the items.

See the issue here: http://www.followupapp.co/learn/comply.html

The code can be viewsourced.
I don't fully understand jssor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed jssor slider in `<div class="card-block">` element.
And there is `1.25rem` padding as below,

```
.card-block {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}
```

Please remove the `padding: 1.25rem;` to solve the problem.